# Confusing behavior of bash cell magics in Jupyter Notebook (Windows 10, Git Bash)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, git-bash

I'm getting odd behavior when trying to use bash cell magics in Jupyter Notebooks on Windows 10, with Git Bash installed.

Cell magics seem to work fine for some bash programs (e.g. which, echo), but not others (e.g. head).

Use of a ! in lieu of bash cell magics works for some commands, but not others. This inconsistency kills notebook compatibility across different operating systems.

Does anyone have any insight into what's happening here?

Here are some examples:

Input:

```
%%bash
which bash
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash
```

Input:

```
!which bash
```

Output:

```
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Input:

```
%%bash
head file.csv
```

Output:

Input:

```
!head file.csv
```

Output:

```
Row,Column,*Target Name,*Sample Name
```

Input:

```
%%bash
echo pizza
```

Output:

```
pizza
```

Input:

```
!echo pizza
```

Output:

```
pizza
```

Comment: I have a somewhat similar problem, did you ever get the to the bottom of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548928/bash-cell-magic-giving-command-not-found-error-in-jupyter-notebook-windo

Comment: Nope! No progress. Admittedly, it's low priority, as the problem is being experienced by some undergrads in our lab. We've just made them switch to using lab computers running Ubuntu instead of their personal Windows laptops.

Comment: I found that '!' uses the default windows shell whereas '%%bash' uses bash. So a workaround is to use '%%cmd' to use all of the commands you can use with '!' but then you face the problems that arise due to the difference between bash and batch. I've also taken the approach of using Ubuntu VMs also. Not sure if anything I said helps at all but just sharing..

Comment: You say Git Bash is installed, but is Jupyter Notebook being launched from Git Bash or from another prompt, e.g., Anaconda?

Comment: Launching via Git Bash. Thanks for clarifying that point!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, as long as Jupyter is launched from a bash-compliant command line such as [Git Bash (MingW64)](https://gitforwindows.org/) or possibly [Ubuntu on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0), bash commands prepended with `!` work in Jupyter Notebook, even on Windows systems.

I'm running windows 10 Pro with Python installed via Anaconda, and bash works when I launch Jupyter via Git Bash, but does **not** when I launch from the Anaconda prompt. For example:

```
>>> !ls
database.sqlite
Weather Data Clustering using k-Means.ipynb

>>>!pip show lxml | grep Version
Version: 4.1.0
```