# Bash cell magic (%%) giving "command not found" error in Jupyter notebook (Windows 7)

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to invoke the `gsutil` command from a cell in a Jupyter notebook, using the bash cell magic `%%bash`, as such:
`%%bash
gsutil`

However I am receiving the following output:
`bash: line 1: gsutil: command not found`
On the other hand, using the exclamation mark syntax gives me the expected result:
`!gsutil`
Gives...
`Usage: gsutil [-D] [-DD] [-h header]... [-m] [-o] [-q] [command [opts...] args...]
Available commands:
  acl             Get, set, or change bucket and/or object ACLs
  cat             Concatenate object content to stdout......`
The `!` syntax doesn't support multi-line commands, and even if it did, as I am collaborating with others, I need the `%%bash` syntax to work for me.
Can anyone enlighten me as to what the reason behind this is and how I can go about solving it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your default shell actually bash?

Comment: If you open up a terminal, run the command `bash` in that terminal, and then run `gsutil` in the resulting bash shell, does it find the command?

Comment: It couldn't find the command no. I've found a work around which is using the `%%cmd` magic, not perfect but don't see another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by using the `%%cmd` magic instead, which I was unaware of. I'll still have to do some tweaking of the bash commands as there are some slight inconsistencies, but still better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `PATH` environment variable might be different in the two environments.  What do you get as the output from

```
!echo $PATH
```

and

```
%%bash
echo $PATH
```

?